# gcloud throwing "Your credentials are invalid. Please run" error

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, gcloud

When trying to build db using `docker-compose run`, I am getting

`Your credentials are invalid. Please run $ gcloud auth login ERROR: 1`

I ran `gcloud auth login` and `gcloud init` as well but did not work. I also tried `gcloud auth application-default login`, it did not work as well.

How can I set the credentials so that I can login and run docker compose to build db?

Comment: What is reporting the error? Something inside a container? Edit your question with details.

Comment: @JohnHanley: it did not give any error inside the container. actually we have a docker compose file, which is used for creating database inside GCP. when i execute docker compose run command it is trying to create a DB and then throwing error `Your credentials are invalid. Please run $ gcloud auth login ERROR: 1`

Comment: Show the Docker Compose file.